# MongoDB's Client in NodeJS is not showing any error or output

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to connect to MongoDB, but it is not showing any output or errors in the terminal.

here's my code

```
const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
const assert = require("assert");

// Connection URL
const url = "mongodb://localhost:27017";

// Database Name
const dbName = "testDB";

// Create a new MongoClient
const client = new MongoClient(url, {useNewUrlParser: true});

// Use connect method to connect to the Server
client.connect(function (err) {

    assert.equal(null, err);
    console.log("Connected successfully to server");

    const db = client.db(dbName);

    client.close();
});
```

`Mongod` is running, it says waiting for connections, so it works correctly. testDB exists, I created it inside `mongo`.

here's my nodeJS output -

```
$ nodemon
[nodemon] 2.0.22
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
```

that's it, nothing else. why is that happening?

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: I expect "Connected successfully to server" output... but it doesn't seem to do it. I added console logs before and after of client.connect, they are executed but callback function in the client.connect is not working.

Comment: If you use the methods described in [MongoDB's Connection Guide](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/fundamentals/connection/), does that work?

Comment: Maybe `await client.connect()`?

Comment: I don't know the details, but it seems [_"callback support"_ was removed in version 5.0.0](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/v5.6.0/HISTORY.md#-breaking-changes-1).